# How to calculate sum over term including rising factorial?

Tags: r, list

I am new to programming and R and would like to compute the following sum

[image]

I used the `pochMpfr` from the `Rmpfr` package for the rising factorial and a for loop in order compute the sum.

```
B=rep(1,k+1)

for (i in 0:k) {
  B[(i+1)]= (-1)^i *choose(k,i)*pochMpfr((-i)*sigma, n)
}

sum(B)
```

Doing so, I get the results as list (including always: mpfr) and thus cannot compute the sum.

Is there a possibility to get the results immediately as a Matrix or to convert the list to vector including only the relevant Elements?

The solution is probably quite easy but I haven't found it while looking through the forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to use a for-loop, this should work:

```
library(Rmpfr)
# You do not define these in your question,
# so I  just take some arbitrary values
k <- 10
n <- 3
sigma <- 0.3

i <- 0:k
B <- (-1)^i *choose(k,i)*pochMpfr((-i)*sigma, n)
sum(B)
## 1 'mpfr' number of precision  159   bits 
## [1] 6.2977401071861993597462780570563107354142915151e-14
```